# PHP: including file written in Bengali does not show text while writing directly in the main page does show up

Tags: php, unicode, multilingual

For index.php, Doctype and HTML tags are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' >
```

Meta tag is:

```
<meta  charset="utf-8"/>
```

If I write Bengali (i.e. Bangla) language  in the webpage, I can view it well. But if I write the Bengali text in a PHP file and then include it in index.php,  only `?` marks are shown.

What is the way to display it properly while including another PHP file?

Comment: used `utf-8` in meta tag. What do you mean by saving... The text is not from database. Just a copy-paste excerpt from a Bengali page.

Comment: utf-8 in meta tag is for client (for tell web browser), while saving the file as UTF-8 is for PHP file encoding (when it's executed).

Comment: which php function is to be used please ?

Comment: nothing just save PHP file as UTF-8!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the PHP file as **UTF-8** without **BOM signature**, you can use notepad2 or nay other text editor that supports encoding.

Comment: please see my comment below the OP.